# В декораторе Python получаю ошибку превышения максимальной глубины рекурсии

Tags: python, рекурсия, декоратор

Реализую две функции: декоратор `print_dichotomy`, выводящий на печать результаты расчета из основной функции `dichotomy_`, и ее саму.

Первоначально проблема возникла, когда декоратор не увидел список из основной функции `eps_list`. Решил так, что название данной переменной прописал полностью: `dichotomy_.eps_list`.

При этом сделал ряд преобразований в декораторе, но получаю ошибку:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

То есть у меня превышена максимальная глубина рекурсии.

Есть модуль, который глубину расширяет, но мне он не помог. Что не так в декораторе? Привожу упрощенный код:

```
import numpy as np

def print_dichotomy(funcs):
    def wrapper(a,b, n, eps_func, eps_arg):
        result = funcs(a,b, n, eps_func, eps_arg)
        res = list(dichotomy_(a,b, n, eps_func, eps_arg))
        func = ', '.join(map(lambda x: f'{f(x):.10f}', res))
        print('Значения функции составляют:\n', func)
        print('Точность расчета: ', dichotomy_.eps_list)
    return wrapper 

def f(x):
    return 1.2-np.log(x)-4*np.cos(2*x)

@print_dichotomy
def dichotomy_(a, b, n, eps_func, eps_arg):  
    dichotomy_.eps_list = []
    grid = np.linspace(a, b, n)
    for x, y in zip(grid, grid[1:]):
        mid = (y + x) / 2
        root = mid
        eps = (y-x) / 2
        dichotomy_.eps_list.append(eps)
        if root:
            yield root

dichotomy_(0.0001, 50, 100, 0.000001, 0.000001)
```

Comment: `list(dichotomy_(...))` ??? Внутри `wrapper` функция `dichotomy_` не может быть упомянута по имени.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, но я с ней получал нужный результат, передавая в print_dichotomy: `def print_dichotomy(dichotomy_)`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, но исправив на `res = list(funcs(a,b, n, eps_func, eps_arg))`, я вернулся, с чего и начинал - к ошибке **AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'eps_list'**

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос что должна делать `dichotomy_` и что должен делать декоратор.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, в оригинале функция `dichotomy_` находит корни уравнения методом дихотомии, а декоратор `print_dichotomy` распечатывает результаты.

Comment: `dichotomy_` не ищет корни. Она не может этого сделать, так как она не вызывает функцию у которой собирается искать корни. Ваш вопрос про декоратор не имеет смысла пока вы не написали правильную `dichotomy_`.

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499554) у вас уже было что-то работающее. Куда подевалась вся функциональность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не вызывайте декорируемую функцию напрямую в декораторе, это приводит к бесконечной рекурсии, потому что в этом случае на самом деле вызывается снова декоратор, а не декорируемая функция.

Могу предложить такое решение: возвращайте `eps_list` точно также через `yield` в конце работы функции:

```py
import numpy as np

def print_dichotomy(funcs):
    def wrapper(a,b, n, eps_func, eps_arg):
        *res, eps_list = funcs(a,b, n, eps_func, eps_arg)
        func = ', '.join(map(lambda x: f'{f(x):.10f}', res))
        print('Значения функции составляют:\n', func)
        print('Точность расчета: ', eps_list)
    return wrapper 

def f(x):
    return 1.2-np.log(x)-4*np.cos(2*x)

@print_dichotomy
def dichotomy_(a, b, n, eps_func, eps_arg):  
    eps_list = []
    grid = np.linspace(a, b, n)
    for x, y in zip(grid, grid[1:]):
        mid = (y + x) / 2
        root = mid
        eps = (y-x) / 2
        eps_list.append(eps)
        if root:
            yield root
    yield eps_list 

dichotomy_(0.0001, 50, 100, 0.000001, 0.000001)
```

Правильность расчётов я не проверял, исправлял только работу декоратора в связке с декорируемой функцией.

Comment: 1. Я бы делал `yield root, eps` - так больше смысла. 2. Код не рабочий полностью, так как `dichotomy_` не делает ничего полезного. В частности она не ищет корни.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Или так. Просто по этому коду зачему-то получается разное кол-во корней и эпсилонов, поэтому я не стал их одновременно отдавать